# Controlling column width in restructuredText tables

Tags: restructuredtext

I have a table that looks like

```
====================    =======
Name1                   Info1
Name2                   Info2
Slightly longer name    Info3
Name4                   Info4
====================    =======
```

and `rst2html` insists on creating the HTML table with the following width specification:

```
<colgroup>
<col width="39%" />
<col width="61%" />
</colgroup>
```

This then makes the `Slightly longer name` in column 1 wrap into two lines.

How can I stop `rst2html` from doing this?

Comment: I tried rst2html from docutils 0.8.1 and I got widths of 74% and 26%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a great solution, but what about just filtering those lines out:

```
rst2html.py file.rst | egrep -v '(colgroup|col width)' > file.html
```

Comment: Fair enough! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a feature request for this at https://sourceforge.net/p/docutils/feature-requests/39/